# Is there a plugin to bundle specified packages in to a vendor file used as runtime?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

## Why I need this?

For example, I want to use `vue`, `vuex`, `vue-router` and `jquery` as externals in my webpack project, so improve speed and avoid unnecessary waste.

## Why not just use externals options

Because that requires four `<script>` tags in my html file. But I want just bundle them in to one file.

## My current solution

Bundle a file separately whose content is:

```
if (window) {
  window.Vue =  require('vue/dist/vue.runtime.common.js')
  window.Vuex = require('vuex/dist/vuex.js')
  window.$ = require('jquery')
  window.VueRouter = require('vue-router/dist/vue-router.common.js')
}
```

Say the output file name is `vendor.xxxx.js`, and I manually add `<script type="text/javascript" src="/vendor.xxxx.js"></script>` to my html template.

## end

This solve the problem. But I don't know if there is already a plugin to handle this. Or is there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

In webpack, you can use the [`expose-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/expose-loader) to expose to the current scope libraries, objects, etc.

In your configuration file, you can add this

```
module: {
  rules: [
   {
     test: require.resolve('vue'),
     use: [
      {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'Vue'
      }
     ]
   },
   {
     test: require.resolve('vuex'),
     use: [
      {
        loader: 'expose-loader',
        options: 'Vuex'
      }
     ]
   }
  ]
}
```

Considering you are creating a web application, the scope will be `window`. I hope it helps